# how to compose transform that can do sql lead/lag functions in Dataflow (Beam)

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I am looking for a way to do sql like lead/lag function in Google Dataflow/Beam. In my case if done in sql, it would be something like

```
lead(balance, 1) over(partition by orderId order by order_Date)
```

In Beam, we parse the input text file and create a class `Client_Orders` to hold the data. For simplicity, let's say we `orderId`, `order_Date` and `balance` members in this class. And we create partitions with the `orderId` by constructing KV in PCollections

```
PCollection <KV<String, Iterable<Client_Orders>>> mainCollection = pipeline.apply(TextIO.Read.named("Reading input file")
.from(options.getInputFilePath()))
.apply(ParDo.named("Extracting client order terms from file") // to produce Client_Orders object
    .apply('create KV...", GroupByKey.<String, Client_Orders>create());
```

In Beam, I know we can do windowing, but that requires in general to set a window size in terms of duration `Windows.of(Duration.standardDays(n))`, but that doesn't seem to help in this case, should I iterate through the PCollection using `order_Date` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is too large per-key to sort in memory, you will want the Beam ["sorter" extension](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/java-extensions/#sorter).

I will explain:

In Beam (hence Dataflow) the elements of a `PCollection` are unordered. This supports the unified programming model whereby the same data yields the same output whether it arrives as a real-time stream or is read from stored files. It also supports isolated failure recovery, provides robustness to network delays, etc.

In many years of massive-scale data processing, almost all uses of global order have turned out to be non-useful, in part because anyone who needs scalability finds a different way to achieve their goals). And even if global ordering exists, processing does not occur in order (because it is parallel) so global ordering would be lost almost immediately. So global ordering is not on the roadmap.

The kind of ordering you need, though, is per key. This is common and useful and often known as "value sorting". When a `GroupByKey` operation yields the grouped values for a key (an element of type `KV<K, Iterable<V>>`) there is often a benefit to a *user-defined* order for the values. Since it is sorting *within a single element* the order is preserved as the element travels through your pipeline. And it is not necessarily prohibitively expensive to sort the values - often the very same operation that groups by key can be leveraged to also sort the values as they are being grouped. This is on the Beam roadmap, but not yet part of the Beam model.

So, for now, there is the above Java-based extension that can sort the values for you.

Comment: thanks, @Kenn, I will give a try. and update afterwards.

Comment: just wonder how to do per-key sort in memory if it is not too large?

Comment: Hi @Kenn, I found this `GroupByKey.SortValuesByTimestamp<K,V>`, and wonder if this is what I need, since I am going to order by order_Date? thanks

Comment: I have tried using "sorter" extension, but got the error `PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable`. I was running with Directrunner for testing, does this extension need to be run in hadoop environment? thanks

Comment: this above error `PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable`  is related to issue in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069550/does-sortvalues-transform-java-sdk-extension-in-beam-only-run-in-hadoop-environm)