# Does SortValues transform Java SDK extension in Beam only run in hadoop environment?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have tried the example code of [SortValues](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/java-extensions/#sorter) transform using `DirectRunner` on local machine (Windows)

```
PCollection<KV<String, KV<String, Integer>>> input = ...

PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<KV<String, Integer>>>> grouped =
input.apply(GroupByKey.<String, KV<String, Integer>>create());

PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<KV<String, Integer>>>> groupedAndSorted =
grouped.apply(SortValues.<String, String, Integer>create(BufferedExternalSorter.options()));
```

but I got the error `PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable`. Does this mean this transform function only works in Hadoop environment?

Comment: This seems strange - the transform appears to be working on my machine. What command are you using to run your pipeline? This class is defined in one of the maven dependencies of the "sorter" module, so I suppose for some reason it's just not making it into the classpath of your invocation.

Comment: Do you have Hadoop installed on your local Windows machine?

Comment: No, and this transform does not require having Hadoop installed. It only requires having the "hadoop-core" library jar in your classpath, and this jar is a maven dependency of the Apache Beam module that contains the SortValues transform, so if you're using Apache Beam as a maven dependency, then you definitely have this jar and you don't need anything else. That's why my hypothesis is that there's simply something wrong with the classpath of your program.

Comment: Ok, does SortValues transform have a dependency on the version of Apache Beam (I am using 0.6)? Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by dependency? SortValues is a *part* of Apache Beam.

Comment: what I mean is that whether the hadoop-core library jar being a maven dependency of Apache beam module depends on the version of beam version. I am using release-0.6.0 Beam, and I just checked that it doesn't contain hadoop-core, and nor does any release version below release-2.0.0.

Comment: Oh I see. Apologies, I was missing some context here. Looks like this JIRA issue specifically talks about this dependency: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1859 - and now I'm no longer sure that the dependency being provided in Beam 2.0.0 is a good thing... So yeah, seems like you need to either use a newer version of Beam which provides it by default, or provide the dependency yourself in your maven file.

Comment: thanks jkff. your input is very helpful here. I just added two hadoop dependencies and it works now. thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149261/discussion-between-bignano-and-jkff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today, if you use Beam with release version below 2.0.0, you will have to add two hadoop dependencies in your maven pom file  for this SortValues module to work.

1. add `hadoop-common` version 2.7.3 or later
2. add `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core` version 2.7.3 or later.

Otherwise, you will just need to use Beam with release version >= 2.0.0.

Comment: I am finding I need to add these dependencies with beam 2.19.0

Comment: beam 2.42.0 and still need to add this to run it locally